# Assigning column names dynamically

Tags: shapefile, gdal, r, attribute-table, rgdal

I have an interesting problem:

I need to batchprocess a few files. I do that in a for-loop, where some operations are performed. Later on I want to write the outcome into an existing shapefile which I do like so:

```
myShapeFile@data <- data.frame(myShapeFile@data,  dynamicColumnName = VALUE)
```

The `dynamicColumnName` gets created dynamically - depending what statistic is performed and so on. Meaning: The name is stored in the variable.
So `dynamicColumnName` could be "2245", in the next iteration of the loop or "0000" or "3334" and so on.

However, the function above does not accept the "characters/integers" stored in the variable. Each column gets named `dynamicColumnName`.

Any ideas how to not let this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply track the column position and then use the names assignment eg.,  `names(myShapeFile@data)[5] <- "2245"` would assign the value "2245" to the fifth column. Keep in mind that when exported an "X." will be added to the name if it is just a number.

Here is an example where I add 10 columns of random numbers and add associated names using an index for the column name.

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y

for(i in 1:10) {
  meuse@data <- data.frame(meuse@data, runif(nrow(meuse)))
    names(meuse)[length(names(meuse))] <- paste("sim",i,sep=".") 
  }  
names(meuse)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply use the `[['NAME']]` operator you can do something like this?

```r
# The vector to add
VALUE <- c(1,2,3)
# Init the table
tab <- data.frame('0001' = VALUE, check.names = FALSE)
# Iterate 
for (i in 2:3) {
   # Build the column name
   cn <- sprintf('%04d',i)
   # Add the dynamic column
   tab[[cn]] <-VALUE +i*10;  
}
# OK ?
tab

  0001 0002 0003
1    1   21   31
2    2   22   32
3    3   23   33

# Only a test to access the columns in a loop
# aggregate will do this much better
for (i in 1:3) {
  # Build the column name
  cn <- sprintf('%04d',i)
  # Do something
  cat(paste('mean:', mean(tab[[cn]]), 
            'min: ', min(tab[[cn]]),
            'max: ', max(tab[[cn]]),
            "\n"))
}

mean: 2 min:  1 max:  3 
mean: 22 min:  21 max:  23 
mean: 32 min:  31 max:  33
```

In a shapefile context, it seems to work too:

```r
library(rgdal)
setwd('~/dev.d/gis-se.d/shapes.d')
poly <- readOGR(".", "polygon_a")
VALUE <- poly@data$gid
poly@data[['0001']] <- VALUE+1
names(poly@data)
[1] "gid"  "0001"

head(poly@data)
  gid 0001
0   2    3
1   3    4
2   4    5
3   5    6
4   9   10

writeOGR(poly,'.','polygon_ax',
    driver="ESRI Shapefile")

$ dbfdump polygon_ax | head -4
    gid                     0001 
     2        3.000000000000000 
     3        4.000000000000000 
     4        5.000000000000000
```

But I can't recommend this kind of breaking the BNF (every variable has to start with a character followed by....).

```
 <ident>  ::= <letter> { <idchar> }
 <idchar> ::= <letter>  |  <digit>  |  _ | .
```

You will loose the capability to use the formulas like in `lm(x ~ y, data = tab)`;